# Limiting size of fineuploader upload element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using a file upload plugin available from http://fineuploader.com/ and downloadable from https://github.com/valums/file-uploader/wiki/Releases.  The plugin does fancy drag-and-drop stuff, but I just want a very basic uploader and am using the FineUploaderBasic option.

I wish to add an upload button on each row of a table.  My code is below, and a live demo is at http://tapmeister.com/test/fineuploader-3.0/test1.html.  The upload button is the second icon on each row.

I got it working, however, the upload clickable area is much larger than just the area taken up by the upload icon. In fact, if you click to the left or below the upload icon, it will trigger an upload.  Looking at the DOM using FireBug, I see that `<input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="file" style="position: absolute; right: 0px; top: 0px; font-family: Arial; font-size: 118px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; cursor: pointer; opacity: 0;">` is added inside the targeted div element, and right after the icon.

How can I limit the size of the input to just the size and position of the original upload div and/or icon?  Thank you

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Fine Uploader - Basic</title>
        <style>
            #myTable td {width:50px;}
            #myTable div {display:inline;}
        </style>
    </head>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="fineuploader-3.0.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            var uploader={
                request: {endpoint: 'server.php'},
                validation: {
                    allowedExtensions: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif', 'png'],
                    sizeLimit: 204800 // 200 kB = 200 * 1024 bytes
                },
                callbacks: {
                    onSubmit: function(id, fileName) {},
                    onUpload: function(id, fileName) {},
                    onProgress: function(id, fileName, loaded, total) {},
                    onComplete: function(id, fileName, responseJSON) {}
                },
                debug: true
            };

            $('#myTable div.upload').each(function(){
                uploader.button=(this);
                new qq.FineUploaderBasic(uploader);
            })

        });
    </script>

    <body>
        <table id="myTable">
            <tr><td>Col1</td><td><img src="folder.png" alt="folder"><div class="upload" title="upload"><img src="upload.png" alt="upload"></div></td><td>Col3</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Col1</td><td><img src="folder.png" alt="folder"><div class="upload" title="upload"><img src="upload.png" alt="upload"></div></td><td>Col3</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Col1</td><td><img src="folder.png" alt="folder"><div class="upload" title="upload"><img src="upload.png" alt="upload"></div></td><td>Col3</td></tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The #myTable div {display:inline;} seemed to cause the problem.  Float is probably the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The upload object's container should have position relative (this is probably optional) but requires overflow hidden to keep the invisible button from rendering outside the container.

```
<table id="myTable">
    <tr>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td class="upload-container"><img src="folder.png" alt="folder"><div class="upload" title="upload"><img src="upload.png" alt="upload"></div></td>
        <td>Col3</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<style>
    .upload-container {
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
    }
</style>
```

Also not required but you should change your upload element to a span instead of a div.  It will still function normally and avoids the W3C compliance issue of a div inside a table cell.

Comment: Yes you can't avoid the inline style as it is harcoded in fineuploader, but as Chris says the inlined size should not overflow outside an "overflow: hidden" element.

However, in case your container needs to avoid "overflow: hidden", you can still either allow a higher z-index values on surrounding areas, or add overriding "!important" CSS rules.